# Java Get and Set returning value 0 on an operation

Tags: java, getter-setter

I'm having trouble getting the value of an operation. All I get as a result is 0. I've tried many things but nothing seems to work. I'm a beginner so I'm sorry if this is something really simple. I looked around for similar problems but I couldn't seem to find one that matched my issue

```
public class Circle {
    double rad, C, D, A, A2, V;

    public double getRad(){
        return rad;
    }

    void setRad(double valueRad){
        this.rad = valueRad;
    }

    public double getCircumference(){
        return C;
    }

    void setCircumference(double Circ){
        Circ = (rad*2)*(Math.PI);
        this.C = Circ;
    }
}
```

And this is my main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Circle res = new Circle();

        res.setRad(5.80);

        System.out.println("The circumference is: "+res.getCircumference()+" cm");
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't calling `setCircumference`, which is responsible for doing the calculation. Call it before `getCircumference` and it will work.

Comment: Also, you don't need to pass anything to `setCircumference`. You're overwriting the passed value anyway.

Comment: And as a general advice, don't start member names (like `C`) with an uppercase letter. The agreed upon standard is to write member and method names in `camelCase`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation code is in the `setCircumference()` method which is never called. When you call the `getCircumference()` method the default `C` field value of `0.0` is returned.

One way to fix it would be to calculate the value in the `getCircumference()` method:

```
public class Circle {
  private double rad;

  public void setRad(double rad) {
    this.rad = rad;
  }

  public double getCircumference() {
    return rad * 2 * Math.PI;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, This fixed my problem. And thank you to everyone else who replied!

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot something. i suggest you use one of this changes:

1:

```
void setRad(double valueRad){
        this.rad = valueRad;
        this.C = (rad*2)*(Math.PI);
    }
```

or 2:

```
public double getCircumference(){
        return (rad*2)*(Math.PI);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By workflow you should call setCircumference before getCircumference

```
   Circle res = new Circle();
   res.setRad(5.80);
   res.setCircumference();
   System.out.println("The circumference is: " + res.getCircumference() + " cm"); 
   // output is The circumference is: 36.4424747816416 cm
```

Circle  class should be

```
class Circle {
double rad, C, D, A, A2, V;

public double getRad(){
    return this.rad;
}

void setRad(double valueRad){
    this.rad = valueRad;
}

public double getCircumference(){
    return this.C;
}

void setCircumference(){
    this.C=(this.rad*2)*(Math.PI);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your `C` will not be updated when you set `rad`.

So when you call the setter for `rad`, you do not only need to update `rad` but also `C`.
Then when you call `getCircumference`, the value of `C` will be up to date with `rad`.